# Postgis query ST_DWithin against lat/long values

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following table called `locations` with the following columns:

- `latitude`
- `longitude`

now I would like to query all entries that are within a specific radius from a given lat/long point.

```
SELECT * FROM locations
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),
    ST_MakePoint(-0.63098, 51.18291),
    100
);
```

The query above explains what data I have as an input and the data I have to query against.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your actual question? -- A point is considered *within* another point, if they are the exact same points. You can play with thresholds, but using [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) would be more straightforward IMHO.

Comment: The question is that the query above returns all entries in the table, not just the ones within the `100m` radius from the input long/lat coordinates. `ST_Distance` returns only the distance between 2 points, what I want to achieve, is return all locations within a specific radius from a point

Comment: yes, that is typically a query with `WHERE ST_Distance(point_in_table, queried_point) < queried_max_distance`

Comment: Tried with both `ST_Distance` and `ST_DWithin` the result is the same. Even though the distance/radius are set to 1m, some of the rows are considerable farer than that.

Comment: Please provide table definitions & sample data and expected output for us to be able to reproduce your findings.

Comment: Sorry, has been answered correctly below and it does the trick.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe, the problem in your query is that you are mixing coordinate systems. ST_DWithin works with distance in SRID units, as stated in the doc `ST_DWithin(geometry g1, geometry g2, double precision distance_of_srid);` Your points are in Lat/Lon, and your distance is in meter. So either you convert your 100m to degrees, or you use another function like ST_Distance_Sphere (fast, inaccurate) or ST_Distance_Spheroid (slower, more accurate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ST_DWithin` can work with both geography and geometry types. `ST_MakePoint` returns a geometry type. When using `ST_DWithin` with a geometry, then it will use distance unit defined by the spatial reference system.

When you want to compare in meters, you first have to cast the values to a geography type. The query then becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM locations
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)::geography,
    ST_MakePoint(-0.63098, 51.18291)::geography,
    100
);
```

An answer explaining more about the difference between geography and geometry is here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-postgis-geography-and-geometry-types

Comment: It looks like converting to geography for a large datasets for `ST_DWithin` takes a long time. How to find the distance unit defined by the spatial reference systems? ex: 4326